# Get object from DataSource Angular MatTable

Tags: angular, datasource, angular-datatables

I have a material data table and get the data from a query to display it. Here is my transaction-history.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Transaction } from '../models/transaction';
import { TransactionService } from '../services/transaction.service';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transaction-history',
  templateUrl: './transaction-history.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transaction-history.component.css']
})
export class TransactionHistoryComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource = new TransactionDataSource(this.transactionService);

  displayedColumns = ['id', 'cust', 'mgrName', 'dept', 'timestamp'];

  constructor(public transactionService: TransactionService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}

export class TransactionDataSource extends DataSource<any>{
  constructor(private transactionService: TransactionService) {
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<Transaction[]> {
    return this.transactionService.getUploaded();
  }
  disconnect() { }
}
```

This displays the data perfectly. But now I want to get the Transaction objects that are being displayed into each row. Right now the dataSource is getting a list of Transactions, but how can I get access to that list? I haven't found any methods on the dataSource object that can do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always save off a copy of the most recent data and expose it via a public property. Like so:

```js
export class TransactionDataSource extends DataSource<any>{
  public data: Transaction[];
  constructor(private transactionService: TransactionService) {
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<Transaction[]> {
    return this.transactionService.getUploaded().pipe(
      tap((data) => this.data = data),
    );
  }
  disconnect() { }
}
```

One disadvantage of this is that modifications to the data property will not be reflected in the table.

Comment: It's disappointing that you cannot connect directly to a query and also be able to make changes to the data that reflect in the table with angular but I appreciate the clarification!